# Sequlize , How to use variables with moment day format in case condtions

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, momentjs

Essentially what i would like for this code to do is that it returns the count of the total amount of tasks created on a particular date i.e if a task was created on Monday it adds 1 to the count if Tuesday it adds 1 to the Tuesday count and so on and so forth. However the code only checks for the first case and runs for it. I feel as if the sequelize.col isn't working as intended I could be wrong

```
  module.exports.Get_Perday_Creation_Reports = async (user_info) => {
  const daily_reports = await Tasks.findAll({
    attributes: [
      [
        sequelize.literal(
          `sum(CASE "${moment(Tasks.sequelize.col("creation_date_time")).format(
            "dddd"
          )}" WHEN "Monday" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )`
        ),
        "Monday",
      ],
      [
        sequelize.literal(
          `sum(CASE "${moment(Tasks.sequelize.col("creation_date_time")).format(
            "dddd"
          )}" WHEN "Tuesday" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )`
        ),
        "Tuesday",
      ],
      [
        sequelize.literal(
          `sum(CASE "${moment(Tasks.sequelize.col("creation_date_time")).format(
            "dddd"
          )}" WHEN "Wednesday" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )`
        ),
        "Wednesday",
      ],
      [
        sequelize.literal(
          `sum(CASE "${moment(Tasks.sequelize.col("creation_date_time")).format(
            "dddd"
          )}" WHEN "Thursday" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )`
        ),
        "Thursday",
      ],
      [
        sequelize.literal(
          `sum(CASE "${moment(Tasks.sequelize.col("creation_date_time")).format(
            "dddd"
          )}" WHEN "Friday" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )`
        ),
        "Friday",
      ],
    ],
    raw: true,
  });

  console.log(daily_reports);
  console.log(moment("2021-09-17 07:48:22").format("dddd"));
};
```

This output is incorrect

[image: The output I'm getting which is wrong]

The database [image: database]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as per my understanding the moments library passes an object to the sql query hence why it never is able to check the rows and produce the case statements on them (e.g. select object{instead of column name})
This can be fixed by utilizing sqls date_format function as followed

```
[
        sequelize.literal(
          `sum(CASE DATE_FORMAT(creation_date_time, '%a')
           WHEN "Mon" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )`
        ),
        "Monday",
      ],
```

Note how it doesn't return The entire name of the day only the abbreviation such as "Mon" "Tues" etc.
Hope this helps someone if they ever run into date formatting